# Symbolic links in the Android filesystem?

Tags: system

Is it possible to create symbolic links in the Android filesystem? If it's possible, how can I do this?

My Android version is 2.1, I'm using Motorola Defy.

Comment: android is not a fileystem. What is the filesystem on which you try to create the symplink? You can use `mount` in [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) to gather this information

Comment: @rds I know that Android is not a file system. I wrote "Android file system" instead of "Android's file system" because I was writting too fast.

Comment: but you still fail to tell what it the underling filesystem you have mounted

Comment: @rds I would assume all androids use the same filesystem. If not then I would assume the filesystem depends on OS version. If these assumptions are incorrect please say. Is it phone specific?

Comment: [How can I make a symlink (or equivalent) inside /storage/emulated/0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203989/218526)

Comment: In the Android root filesystem there are many shortcuts/links.  I think the original post is about how those are created.  I would also like to know this.  Searching for shortcuts on Google only gives results for adding shortcuts to home screen, but many people want to make a shortcut from one directory to a directory in another location.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Android does support symbolic links, but certain file systems (e.g. FAT or RFS) do not and you cannot create symbolic links in those partitions. If your device uses a filesystem that supports symbolic links (e.g. ext2, ext3, ext4, yaffs2) then you should be able to use `ln -s` from the Terminal Emulator.

Answer (score 8):

I think [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/216332/is-there-anything-like-a-link-or-shared-mount-point-for-fat32-folders-in-linux-an) answers your question, i.e. that the FAT filesystem on the SD card does not support symlinks.

Just to clarify (and as reflected in the SU question/answers I linked): the Android OS supports symlinks, but the FAT filesystem on the SD card does not.

Comment: You're always free to format your SD Card with a modern filesystem (if you don't use it on an archaic operating system, of course)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do this via the `mount -o bind /old/dir /new/dir` command as discussed here
https://superuser.com/a/377737/45344

You need root I guess.

Comment: This is the kind of changes which would be lost on reboot.

Comment: This is not a symbolic link; it's a bind mount.

Answer (score 4):

You were dealing with `/storage/emulated/0/Videos`

Android like to make use of the `/dev/fuse` partition.  I do not think you can make a symbolic link in this filesystem.  On my htc desire 510, I see this:

```
/busybox df /storage/emulated/0                                          
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/fuse              1057284   1040844     16440  98% /mnt/shell/emulated
```

#

There is some weird stuff going on with /storage

Comment: Is this supposed an answer to the question?

Comment: `/dev/fuse` is not a partition, it's a character device which programs use to communicate with kernel in order to mount **F**ilesystem in **U**ser**S**pac**E**. @FindOutIslamNow yes partial answer, because Android's FUSE implementation doesn't support symlinks.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer!