# How can I make a symlink (or equivalent) inside /storage/emulated/0?

Tags: rooting, external-sd, internal-sd

So, I have rooted my phone (GT-i9505 with android 5.0.1) and I would like to move my WhatsApp folder to my external SD card to save 3GB on internal storage. This is what I tried so far.

### EDIT: solution found

So, after all the option #2 seemed to be the right one, but it needed some tweaks to make it work. As suggested by [Irfan Latif](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203989/155472) , the problem was that the mount point has to be created in a global mount namespace, otherwise other apps will not see it, so the commands to use are:

```
su -mm
mount -o bind /data/sdext2/AppData/WhatsAppMedia /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media
```

But that may not be enough! It still didn't work until I made sure that the namespace of root was global. To do that I don't know any universal way, but what worked for me was going in the SuperSU app settings and uncheck the option `mount namespace separation`.

That really depends on the SU app that you have installed.

### Option 1: symlink

The first thing that I thought was to make a symlink, so that was the command that I used:

```
ln -s "/data/sdext2/AppData/WhatsAppMedia" "/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media"
```

I had already created a second partition on my external SD card (ext4) that is mounted in `/data/sdext2`

However that returns `operation not permitted` when using the terminal emulator (yes I did `su`) and an error with any root file manager app that I tried.

After some research I figured out that for some reason, although `/storage/emulator/0` is in an ext partition, it is treated in a differente way so that it doesn't support symlink inside (correct me if I'm wrong).

So, onto the next thing

### Option 2: mount

According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/216332/is-there-anything-like-a-link-or-shared-mount-point-for-fat32-folders-in-linux-a/377737#377737), the following command should mount the folder on external SD card in another folder in the internal SD card, without the need for a symlink

```
mount -o bind "/data/sdext2/AppData/WhatsAppMedia" "/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media"
```

However, while running the command doesn't return any error the folder in `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media` is still empty, so I don't really know how to handle this.

### Option 3: symlink in /data/media/

I followed the instructions on [this post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=21376753#post21376753) and made the symlink in `/data/media/0` instead of storage, so using this command:

```
ln -s "/data/sdext2/AppData/WhatsAppMedia" "/data/media/0/WhatsApp/Media"
```

This time the link is created! However ...

Although an `ls` in `/data/media/0/WhatsApp/Media` revealed that the link was successful, `cd /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media` returns a very irritating `no such file or directory` and that is confirmed by the file explorer that shows an empty folder with a blank file icon.

### My thoughts

First of all, I now discovered that I really hate android. Now, stated this, here's what I think might help doing:

- **moving my sdcard files somewhere else:** if the rest of the root filesystem supports symlink (which it seems like it does), I might even move the folder `/storage/emulated/0` somewhere else and make a new link to it, but I don't know if that would solve the problem

That's it for now, I will update with more options when I think about them...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**ANDROID STORAGE:**

On [Android 5](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example#android_5_x_emulated):

```
/sdcard >S> /storage/emulated/legacy >S> /mnt/shell/emulated/0
/mnt/shell/emulated >E> /data/media
```

On [Android 6+](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/#runtime_permissions):

```
# USER-ID of current user in case of multiple users, normally "0"

# for apps
# VIEW is one of "read" or "write" and /storage to VIEW bind mount is inside a separate mount namespace for every app
/sdcard >S> /storage/self/primary
/storage/self >B> /mnt/user/USER-ID
/mnt/user/USER-ID/primary >S> /storage/emulated/USER-ID
/storage/emulated >B> /mnt/runtime/VIEW/emulated
/mnt/runtime/VIEW/emulated >E> /data/media

# for services/daemons/processes in root namespace
/sdcard >S> /storage/self/primary
/storage >B> /mnt/runtime/default
/mnt/runtime/default/self/primary >S> mnt/user/0/primary
/mnt/user/0/primary >S> /storage/emulated/0
/storage/emulated >B> /mnt/runtime/default/emulated
/mnt/runtime/default/emulated >E> /data/media
```

<sup>`>S>` for symlink, `>E>` for emulated and `>B>` for bind mount</sup>

In short, `/sdcard` points to `/data/media/0` through `FUSE` or `sdcardfs` emulation. This is to restrict unauthorized access of apps/processes to private media on SD card. Read [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526).

**SYMLINKS:**

Now `/sdcard` is not a real but emulated storage which represents a FAT/vFAT/FAT32 filesystem (for backward compatibility and permission management) which [doesn't support symlinks](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218944/218526) (and other things including *NIX permissions and `ioctls` like `FS_IOC_FIEMAP`). So the Option 1 and 3 of yours won't work whether you create symlink directly on emulated storage or try to emulate the symlink already created on ext4.

**BIND MOUNT:**

This is the commonly used alternate of symlink for FAT family of filesystems. What you have tried in Option 2 should work. This is what apps like `Apps2SD` do. But there is again a constraint: `mount namespace`. You need to bind mount in global/root mount namespace so that the mount is visible to all apps:

```
su -mm -c 'mount -o bind "/data/sdext2/AppData/WhatsApp Media" "/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media"'
```

On Android 6+ this needs to be bind mounted on each VIEW (default, read, write) separately for all apps to work.

You can make it permanent by setting ***Mount Namespace Mode*** to ***Global*** in Magisk or by disabling ***Mount Namespace Separation*** in SuperSU. For details see this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197959/partition-gets-unmounted-automatically-in-android-oreo/200449#200449).

---

**RELATED:**

- [What is "/storage/emulated/0"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)
- [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526)

Answer (score 1):

Install MiXplorer from this XDA thread [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1523691) → browse to the path using MiXplorer → click on `+` at the bottom → choose "Create symbolic link".