# Is it possible to create shortcut in Android file system without root?

Tags: file-system

Android system doesn't provide ways to  create shortcut in file system.
I have tried using `termux` to create shortcut in my file system, but I don't have the authority.
Is there a way to create shortcut of files and directories in Android file system without root?

Comment: As much as I know, the Android OS supports symlinks by which it exposes the /data/media directory as /storage/emulated/0 directory. So, creating symlinks inside another symlinked file system is not possible. If you can access the /data/media directory, you can create a symlink, but accessing that directory requires root access.

Comment: @NiaBie by shortcut you mean symlink? From where to where you want to create shortcut? @Puspam Adak `/storage/emulated/0` is not a symlink but emulated filesystem which doesn't support symlinks.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a symlink (or equivalent) inside /storage/emulated/0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/how-can-i-make-a-symlink-or-equivalent-inside-storage-emulated-0)