# Why can't WhatsApp write to bind mounts?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, bind-mount

I moved all the data of WhatsApp to `/mnt/media_rw/6333-6461/WhatsApp`, where 6333-6461 is my external SD card. I opened WhatsApp to find that I could not open any previously downloaded data. This is expected.

Now, I executed the following commands in Termux:

```
$ su
# mount -o bind /mnt/runtime/write/6333-6461/WhatsApp /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp
```

When I opened WhatsApp, I could see all the data that I had previously downloaded. But now I cannot send or receive anything - all sending fails, camera access from WhatsApp fails, and downloading fails.

Evidently WhatsApp is not being able to write onto the bind mount. Any solution to the problem?

My phone, a Samsung Galaxy On7, Android 6.0.1, is rooted with Magisk 20.1 and running stock ROM.

Comment: What are the permissions of the WhatsApp folder?

Comment: mount -o bind /storage/6333-6461/WhatsApp /storage/emulated/0/6333-6461/WhatsApp

Comment: @alecxs I have tried that; WhatsApp cannot even read previously downloaded data, let aside write data.

Comment: must be written for older android days when external sd was just named sdcard1, so don't know for sure it works. i just created a empty file `.sdcard1` in the WhatsApp folder to let the script know sdcard1 should be bind mounted http://www.mediafire.com/file/l6fz52s6n1cgbjh/whatsapp2sd.zip i was wrong it wasn't /storage and i believe it only worked on early stage (as init.d script)

Comment: mount -o bind /mnt/media_rw/6333-6461/WhatsApp /data/media/0/WhatsApp

Comment: @alecxs Unfortunately that mounting too doesn't work. I have tried these permutations previously. Samsung binds the WhatsApp folders to ````libunionfs```` instead of any specific directory. I don't know how to achieve this through bash.

Comment: forgot to mention i set namespace global https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't WhatsApp write to bind mounts?
>
> ```
> # mount -o bind /mnt/runtime/write/6333-6461/WhatsApp /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp
> ```

Apps cannot directly access `/mnt/runtime/write/6333-6461` or `/mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/` because `/mnt/runtime` is only traverse-able by root. Apps access `/storage/emulated/0` or `/sdcard` (symlink to the former) which is bind-mounted to `/mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/` for apps with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. External SD card is accessible at `/storage/6333-6461` in the same way.

When `/mnt/runtime/write/6333-6461/WhatsApp` is bind-mounted at `/mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp`, WhatsApp will actually try to write to external SD card which is not allowed at least since Android 4.4. This is controlled by using permissions `READ|WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` / `READ|WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE`, GID `everybody (9997)` / `media_rw (1023)` and mount namespaces. See details in [How to move files to external SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526).

> Any solution to the problem?

There are some workarounds to set required permissions using `FUSE` or `sdcardfs` when bind mounting external directories. For details see [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526)