# Symlink temporary file

Tags: adb, backup, storage, signal-private-messenger

I'm attempting to backup my Signal chats totalling almost 15GB, which presents a challenge in my 32GB phone. I simply have no space to do it, and even stripping the system of pretty much all apps except Signal is not quite enough, and naturally would be quite a lot of work.
So, I was trying to create some sort of symlink between my external SD card and the Signal backup directory. I managed to do it via a `su -M` session (via `adb shell` but Termux also works) by using `mount -o bind /storage/<sdcardID>/Signal /storage/emulated/0/Signal` (having previously created that Signal dir on main storage). Files I create are perfectly mirrored and actually live on the external storage, however, the [temporary file Signal creates](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/main/app/src/main/java/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/jobs/LocalBackupJob.java#L121) for the backup is nowhere to be found. It doesn't even appear when I `ls` either path, yet it does appear when I navigate to it using any file explorer app.

How come? Is there a way to correctly link that?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Backups have been improved for Android 10, but I am on 9, so that's a no go.

Comment: Have you read https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/how-can-i-make-a-symlink-or-equivalent-inside-storage-emulated-0 (even if it is about an pretty old Android version)?

Comment: Yes, that was what lead me to `su -M` (equivalent to `su -mm`), correctly setting the Mount Namespace Mode in Magisk and using mount binds. It works well except it seems to not "track" temporary files.